# Как лучше сверстать подобный слайдер?

Tags: css, css3

Саму анимацию то сделать не трудно, вот только стрелки эти, как сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похожая картинка там на скриншоте: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно составить такую раздвигающуюся стрелку из трех компонентов: хвоста стрелки (`.arrow__left`), раздвигающейся части (`.arrow__center`) и острия стрелки (`.arrow__right`). Центральная часть изначально будет нулевой ширины, при наведении ширина будет увеличиваться. Хвост и остриё обрезать при помощи свойства `clip-path`. Только обратите внимание на ограниченную поддержку этого свойства браузерами, для фоллбека рекомендую использовать `@supports`.

```css
.arrow {
  display: flex;
}

.arrow__left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/vt1Bu3m.jpg);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 50%, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
}

.arrow__right {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/vt1Bu3m.jpg);
  background-position: -100px 0;
  transition: all .2s;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
}

.arrow__center {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/vt1Bu3m.jpg);
  background-position: -100px 0;
  width: 0;
  transition: width .2s;
}

.arrow:hover .arrow__center {
  width: 400px;
}

.arrow:hover .arrow__right {
  background-position: -500px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class=arrow>
  <div class=arrow__left>
  
  </div>
  <div class=arrow__center>
  
  </div>
  <div class=arrow__right>

  </div>
</div>
```